# Why Unicode character for "Hearts" symbol fails with HTML

Tags: html, unicode, xhtml

According to my understanding the following HTML markup should display a heart symbol, but it is not. What I am missing?
I got the data about Unicode characters here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html_special_characters#Character_entity_references_in_HTML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hearts</title>
</head>
<body>
&#2665;
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you would explain what you're seeing that you don't expect, and also how the data is being displayed.  Is this a file that you're opening locally with a browser? Is it being sent from a server?

Comment: Given that you're using UTF-8, you can just paste the ♥ character into your source file. There's no particular need to use a `&#...;` character reference.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The XML/HTML `&#NNNN;` notation is for decimal values. Try using the `&#xNNNN;` form to force it to interpret it as hexadecimal, or, alternatively, use the decimal value.

Answer (score 33):

Encoded entities:

```
&hearts; &#x2665; &#9829;
&#x2661; &#x2764; &#x2765;
```

Output:

♥ ♥ ♥
♡ ❤ ❥

Note the `x` required.

Without the `x`:
`&#2661; &#2665;`
੥ ੩

Comment: Here are some more HTML codes that you can use for different heart symbols: http://heartsymbol.love/list

Answer (score 8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hearts</title>
</head>
<body>
&#x2665;

&hearts;
</body>
```

Works in FireFox/Chrome/IE. Looks like you forgot the "x" bit in your code.